# Proving that Union of a finite number of complete subsets of metric space $(X,d)$ is complete.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, proof-verification

We have following 3 definitions.

**Definition:** Suppose that $(X,d)$ is a metric space. A sequence $(\textbf{x}_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ of points in $X$ is said to be a *Cauchy sequence*, if, given any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N$ such that $d(\textbf{x}_m,\textbf{x}_n)<\epsilon$ whenever $N\le n<m$.

**Definition:** Suppose that $(X,d)$ is a metric space, and that $S\subseteq X$. We say that $S$ is *complete* if and only if every Cauchy sequence in $S$ has a limit in $S$.

**Definition:** Suppose that $(X,d)$ is a metric space, and that $S\subseteq X$. We say that $S$ is *compact* if and only if every sequence in $S$ has a convergent subsequence with limit in S.

---

**And are the proofs of the 3 following theorem correct?**

**Theorem 1:** Suppose that $(X,d)$ is a metric space. Intersection of any collection of complete subsets of $X$ is complete.

**Proof:** Let $(\textbf{x}_n)$ be a Cauchy sequence in $\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i$, an intersection of any collection $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ of complete subsets of $X$. Since $(\textbf{x}_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i$, it is a Cauchy sequence in $A_1$. Since $A_1$ is complete, $\textbf x_n \rightarrow \textbf x$ where $\textbf x \in A_1$. Similarly, since $(\textbf{x}_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i$, it is a Cauchy sequence in $A_2$. Since $A_2$ is complete, $\textbf x \in A_2$. Without loss of generality, $\textbf x \in A_i$ for all $I\in I$.

$\therefore x\in \bigcap_{i\in I}A_i$. Hence $\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i$, the intersection of any collection of complete subsets of $X$ is complete.

**Theorem 2:** Suppose that $(X,d)$ is a metric space. The intersection of a compact set and a closed set in $X$ is compact.

**Proof:** Denote $E\subseteq X$ to be the compact set in $X$ and $W$ to be a closed set in $X$.

We know that a compact set in a metric space is also complete and complete sets are closed in $X$. Therefore $E$ is closed. Now, $E \cap W$ is a closed set, since intersection of any collection of closed sets is closed. And $E \cap W \subseteq E$.

Now, suppose that $(\textbf{x}_n)$ be a sequence in $E \cap W$ and so in $E$. Since $E$ is compact, $(\textbf{x}_n)$ has a convergent subsequence with limit $\textbf x$, say. If $\textbf x=\textbf x_n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then clearly $\textbf x \in E\cap W$. If $\textbf x \neq \textbf x_n$ for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then $\textbf x$ is an accumulation point of $E\cap W$, so that $\textbf x \in E\cap W$ since $E\cap W$ is closed.

Hence, $E\cap W$, the intersection of a compact set and a closed set in $X$ is compact, since every sequence in $E\cap W$ has a convergent subsequence in $E\cap W$.

**Theorem 3:** Suppose that $(X,d)$ is a metric space. The intersection of any collection of compact sets in $X$ is compact.

**Proof:** Let $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ be any collection compact sets of $X$. For all $I\in I$, $A_i$ is a closed set, since compact sets are closed. Moreover, intersection of any collection of closed sets in $X$ is closed, hence $\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i$ is a closed set. Also, we have $\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i \subseteq A_1$.

Now, suppose that $(\textbf{x}_n)$ be a sequence in $\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i$ and so in $A_1$. Since $A_1$ is compact, $(\textbf{x}_n)$ has a convergent subsequence with limit $\textbf x$, say. If $\textbf x=\textbf x_n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then clearly $\textbf x \in \bigcap_{i\in I}A_i$. If $\textbf x \neq \textbf x_n$ for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then $\textbf x$ is an accumulation point of $\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i$, so that $\textbf x \in \bigcap_{i\in I}A_i$ since $\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i$ is closed.

Hence, $\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i$, the intersection of any collection of compact sets in $X$ is compact, since every sequence in $\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i$ has a convergent subsequence in $\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i$.

---

**And how would you prove the following theorem?**

**Theorem:** Suppose that $(X,d)$ is a metric space. Union of a finite number of complete subsets of $X$ is complete. ($(X,d)$ may or may not be complete)

I find proving this last theorem ok if $X$ was complete, but when we don't know whether $X$ itself is a complete metric space or not, I found that it is hard to prove this theorem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your proofs seem fine at first glance, except you need not assume that your index sets are countable.

As for your question : Let $S = S_1\cup S_2\cup \ldots S_n$ be the union of a finite number of complete subsets of $X$. Choose a Cauchy sequence $(x_n) \in S$, then there is some $k \in \{1,2,\ldots, n\}$ such that infinitely many $x_n$'s are in $S_k$ (otherwise the entire sequence would be a finite set, which is the trivial case we can ignore).

Thus, there is a subsequence $(x_{n_j}) \in S_k$ which must have a limit in $S_k$ (since $S_k$ is complete). However, if a subsequence of a Cauchy sequence converges to a point, then the entire sequence converges to that point. (Why?)

Hence that point is in $S$